# How to get list from spring controller to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

**This is my script**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'request/batch/details',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {

        alert("ok");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**and this is my controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/request/batch/details"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public  List<Batch> SentAllBatchs() {

    List<Batch> allBatches = service.getAllBatches();

    for (Batch allBatche : allBatches) {
        System.out.println(allBatche.getBatchName());
    }
    return allBatches;
}
```

**when I run this it throwing a error**

405 Method Not Allowed..

did I do anything wrong?
help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

please add the below mvn artifacts if missing in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and also check if you have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Previously the question referred the error code as 406, so the answer refers to that 406 error code

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your security/logs
2. Add @ResponseBody or ResponseEntry as a respnose to your controller

Andtry to add leading slash in your request ;)

Comment: you mean like this?
 public @ResponseBody List<Batch> SentAllBatchs() {

Comment: Something like this, yes. It's not nesesary if it's RestController, but it's not present in your question.